# Database migration with Dbeaver using 14 GB RAM

Tags: database, oracle, migration, dbeaver

I'm doing a database migration from Oracle tables to SQL Server tables. Two of the three tables were successful during the first try, mostly because they didn't have that many rows as the third (about 3,5 million rows with around 30 columns). I took me around 15 attempts   to accomplish the migration process, because Dbeaver use all the RAM available (around 14 GB).

- Migration using 10.000/100.000 segments, CPU use to 100% for many minutes, Dbeaver crashed because the JVM use all assigned memory.

After increasing the JVM memory to 14 GB, migration crashed because the system didn't have more RAM available.

I did change the segment size many times with no results. I ended up using the 'direct Query' and after 1,5 hours it finished successfully.

The question is: Why Dbeaver keeps using RAM without GC cleaning it? 
How can I change the beauvoir of the GC to be more 'eager'?

Thanks.

Comment: Since it didn't have any response. I opened a issue in Dbeaver's github repository. https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/issues/2125